# Web Storage: How to edit object members

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

In TypeScript, I have a wrapper class around the Web Storage API. To make the storage easy to use, I initialized a class property for every item my application needs to store. Below is my wrapper class (written in TypeScript)

export class **StorageService**

```
get Storage(){return localStorage}
get testData(){return this.getItem('testData')}
set testData(val){this.setItem('testData',val)}

getItem(key:string){return JSON.parse(this.Storage.getItem(key))}
setItem(key:string, data:any){this.Storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data))}
removeItem(key){this.Storage.removeItem(key)}
clear(){this.Storage.clear()}
```

elsewhere in the application, I want to interact with object `testData` and its member properties. The following works fine:

```
storage.testData = {name:'Mary',age:6};
console.log(storage.testData); //initial object is retrieved
```

However, if I try to change a property of testData rather than set the whole object, the `setItem` method is never called and the contents of the storage are not changed.

```
storage.testData.age = 10;
console.log(storage.testData); //{name:'Mary',age:6} <- age was not changed
```

The intuitive fix is to first retrieve the stored object, then update it, and finally store the updated value

```
var temp = storage.testData;
temp.age = 10;
storage.testData = temp;
console.log(storage.testData); //{name:'Mary',age:10} <- age is updated
```

This is fine on a small object but it doesn't scale well. Imagine that testData has 50 or 60 properties, and that at multiple points in the app, I need to change just 1 or 2 of them. It doesn't make sense to have to set every property every time.  Anyway, I may not be able to change the rest of the application; I only provide the storage interface.

My question is: how can I expose a storage method that allows setting/changing properties of the objects in storage directly rather than having to supply the full object to store every time? Ideally the consuming code would just call `store.testData.age = value` to edit the currently stored value.

PS: Also this may be for another topic but if accessing localStorage a lot would really slow down the app (as per the 1st comment below), maybe I'm not using Web Storage as it's intended? Perhaps my wrapper could store values in memory but push them all to storage at set intervals; say every 3 minutes? I used to have strictly in memory objects reflect the state of the app, but all is lost when the user navigates away or refreshes the page

Comment: What doesn't scale well is stringifying and storing the whole object each time you make a change, if you want to do lots of changes. Your current way (saving at the end) is the appropriate one. By the way, `Storage` objects have getters and setters already.

Comment: More info please. Both ways above would involve stringifying at every change no? Also this may be for another topic but if accessing localStorage a lot would really slow down the app, maybe I'm not using storage as it's intended? Perhaps my wrapper could store values in memory but push them all to storage at set intervals; say every 3 minutes? I used to have strictly in memory objects reflect the state of the app, but all is lost when the user navigates away or refreshes the page.

Comment: No. with `var temp = storage.testData` you access the storage and parse JSON. Then you can do a huge amount of changes to the object, which are not saved to storage (so it's fast). Finally, you stringify and save with `storage.testData = temp`.

Comment: I understand. What do you think of the 2nd part of my comment?

Comment: Not sure, that depends on your app, and how the system implements the storage. You can try it and measure if it improves the performance or not.

Comment: Doesn't it go without saying that continuous access to memory and occasional access to storage is faster than continuous access to storage? Anyway you gave me an idea and I wrote up what I intend to do. Would appreciate any feedback you have on my answer.

Comment: Looks good. Maybe also try to commit in a `beforeunload` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the OP, I may not be able to make changes to the interface. The calling code ideally would be able to make changes to the member properties of objects in storage. I think I'll try a hybrid approach. Store items in memory, but every set interval (or upon a specific command), commit them to storage.  Below is my simplified **StorageService** in TypeScript

```
//push items to storage regularly
constructor() {this.restore();this.intervalID = setInterval(()=>this.commit(),this.COMMIT_INTERVAL*1000)}

Storage = window.localStorage;
COMMIT_INTERVAL = 60;//interval, in seconds, upon which changes are saved to storage
private intervalID:number;
private keys = ['testData', 'testData2']; //key names used set items in storage

//when data is accessed, return it from memory. If not there (eg after a page refresh), then from storage
private _testData = null;
public get testData(){return this._testData || this.getItem(this.keys[0])}
public set testData(val){this._testData = val} //we store in memory; not directly in storage until commit() is called.

//remove each value from memore and clear web storage
public clear(){
    this.keys.forEach(key=>this['_'+key]=null,this);
    this.Storage.clear()
}

// store memory data in web storage
public commit(){    
    this.keys.forEach(key => this.setItem(key,this['_'+key]),this);
}

//restore items from web storage. This is done in the constructor
private restore(){
    this.keys.forEach(key => this[key] = this.getItem(key) || this[key])
}

//the methods that actually connect to storage are all private. Calling code must use commit() to interact with storage
private getItem(key:string){
    return JSON.parse(this.Storage.getItem(key));
}
private removeItem(key){
    this.Storage.removeItem(key);
}
private setItem(key:string, data:any){
    this.Storage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

This service allows the API that the calling code uses to remain the same: `testData.age = 10` will update the object in memory, and eventually (when `commit()` is called) in storage.

Please give me feedback.  I'm new to coding and weary of costly mistakes.